# Symfony2 form validation always returning ERROR: This value should not be blank

Tags: php, forms, validation, symfony, symfony-forms

I have a strange problem using a form in Symfony2.

First i've added the validation as `annotations` inside the entity class `Job` here:

```
class Job
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Choice(callback="getTypeValues")
     */
    protected $type;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    protected $company;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $logo;

    /**
     * @Assert\Image()
     */
    protected $file;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     * @Assert\Url()
     */
    protected $url;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    protected $position;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    protected $location;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    protected $description;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    protected $how_to_apply;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    protected $token;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $is_public;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $is_activated;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Email()
     */
    protected $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    protected $expires_at;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    protected $created_at;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $updated_at;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="jobs")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    protected $category;
}
```

I've created a `JobType` class and used it inside a form. So i can add jobs.

```
class JobType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('type', 'choice', array('choices' => Job::getTypes(), 'expanded' => true))
            ->add('category')
            ->add('company')
            ->add('file', 'file', array('label' => 'Company logo', 'required' => false))
            ->add('url')
            ->add('position')
            ->add('location')
            ->add('description')
            ->add('how_to_apply', null, array('label' => 'How to apply?'))
            ->add('is_public', null, array('label' => 'Public?'))
            ->add('email')
        ;
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
                'data_class' => 'Ibw\JobeetBundle\Entity\Job',
            ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'job';
    }
}
```

Here's my controller:

```
public function createAction(Request $request)
{
    $entity = new Job();
    $form = $this->createForm(new JobType(), $entity);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if($form->isValid())
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('ibw_job_preview', array(
                'company'   => $entity->getCompanySlug(),
                'location'  => $entity->getLocationSlug(),
                'position'  => $entity->getPositionSlug(),
                'token'     => $entity->getToken(),
            )));
    } else {
        return new Response(var_dump($form->getErrorsAsString()));
//            return new Response($form->getErrorsAsString());
//          return $this->render('IbwJobeetBundle:Job:new.html.twig', array(
//                  'form' => $form->createView(),
//              ));
    }
}
```

Now when i do `var_dump($form->getErrorsAsString())` I get:

```
string 'ERROR: This value should not be blank.
type:
    0:
        No errors
    1:
        No errors
    2:
        No errors
category:
    No errors
company:
    No errors
file:
    No errors
url:
    No errors
position:
    No errors
location:
    No errors
description:
    No errors
how_to_apply:
    No errors
is_public:
    No errors
email:
    No errors
' (length=355)
```

Or when i do `var_dump($form->getErrors())` I get:

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    object(Symfony\Component\Form\FormError)[614]
      private 'message' => string 'This value should not be blank.' (length=31)
      protected 'messageTemplate' => string 'This value should not be blank.' (length=31)
      protected 'messageParameters' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      protected 'messagePluralization' => null
```

I have no idea what generates this `ERROR: This value should not be blank.` error. I'm having hard times figuring it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you getting these errors on the GET requests when the form should be displayed in the view or do you mean when you POST the form to the controller to process the form?

Comment: Is just an idea ... I think you should either @Assert\NotBlank() OR using the callback function - not both.

Comment: @KenHannel This happens when the POST controller process the posted form. So yea in the POST request.

Comment: @stwe Just tried to remove `NotBlank()` still no good. The same problem occurs.

Comment: have you cleared your cache?

Comment: @stwe Although i'm using the development environment but yea, i've cleared it.

Comment: `$token` => `@Assert\NotBlank()`?

Comment: @cheesemacfly You mean i should remove the assertion ?

Comment: Yeah, try to see of it helps!

Comment: Don't forget to clear your (symfony+apc/opcode) cache after changing assert annotations ...

Comment: Removing `NotBlank` from `$token` did it !.. But i wonder why ? I haven't included `$token` in the form anyway !

Comment: Validation in the first place does not have anything to do with the form but the entity itself. you should create a [**validation-group**](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html#validation-groups) for the form and second one to validate your entity once the token has been set.

Comment: @nifr I've added validation group and it's working. But i'm not quite following why the error is raised here. Could you elaborate more?

Comment: Post the template/view that renders the form. I'm guessing that you might have a hidden field that isn't rendered (like a csrf token or something)

Comment: The problem is that the NotBlanck validator not add properti name when add validation error. See source code: [NotBlank](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/v2.4.4/src/Symfony/Component/Validator/Constraints/NotBlankValidator.php) and for example a [Date](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/v2.4.4/src/Symfony/Component/Validator/Constraints/DateValidator.php) . I don't know why NotBlank not add name of propertie

Answer (score 5):

I've just had the same problem. I got a global error `ERROR: This value should not be blank`, but there was not any errors to a specific field.

[nifr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1832745/nifr) was right, validation is in fact applied to the underlying object. The question is whether or not the object is valid after the form has applied the submitted data to it. http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#form-validation

The reason for this problem is that some fields of the object are not valid after a form submission and these fields are not included in the form. To solve this problem, you can pass valid data to the fields of the object before validation, or use validation groups to validate the object against only some of the constraints on the class.

Answer (score 4):

remove the following:

```
token:
     - NotBlank: ~
```

from `src/Ibw/JobeetBundle/Resources/config/validation.yml`

Comment: Mark this as right answer, this helped me to get my form valid.

Answer (score 2):

as @cheesemacfly mentioned, your problem is in the "token" field

it's asserted to be "not blank" but it is not included in the form, that's why the error is not bound to any of the form fields and is rather a global error for the form because the validation happens on the entity, not on the form(different than in symfony 1.4) and so the validation mechanism can't bind it to a field in a form because this property(token) doesn't have a field in the form